# Смена параметров NavigationHeader при нажатии на пункт в NavigationView

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо менять пункты "A" "B" "C" при нажатии на любой из пунктов 1,2,3,4 и тд.
Я никогда не делал этого, думал всё просто, но с ходу не получилось - словил пару ошибок и решил задать вопрос, кто знает. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте код в котором вы пытаетесь что-то сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понимаю это стандартная заготовка проекта с боковым меню из Android Studio.

1. Удалите из activity_main.xml у элемента NavigationView строку *app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"*.
2. И добавте строки в MainActivity.java выделеные звездочками (жирным в примере кода, почему то не выделяет)

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   **private TextView textView;**

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
       fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .setAction("Action", null).show();
           }
       });

       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
               this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
       drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
       toggle.syncState();

       NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
       **View navHeaderMain = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);**
       **textView = (TextView) navHeaderMain.findViewById(R.id.textView);**
       navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
           // Handle the camera action
           **textView.setText("nav_camara");**
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
           **textView.setText("nav_gallery");**
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
           **textView.setText("nav_slideshow");**
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
           **textView.setText("nav_manage");**
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

       } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

       }

       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       return true;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я уже сделал.

Comment: Кстати, с версии support либы 23.1.1 есть метод `NavigationView.getHeaderView();`